# Would have had problem

Tags: light-verbs

> Doctor informed the court on Monday that it had terminated the over 22-week pregnancy of a minor rape survivor as continuing with it **would have had** severe impact on girl's physical and mental health.

Why **would have had** why don't **would have impacted on girl's physical and mental health** only?

Comment: Closed cross-site duplicate by same OP: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/502155/would-have-had-problem

Comment: Always tell us [where a sentence like this came from](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Comment: In passing, the grammar is a little clipped, it would normally be something like "Doctor**s** informed the court ... **they** had ...  **a** severe impact on **the** girl's ...".  Was it copied fully from the original?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that in the legal field, people often try to use the exact words of a statute or decision.

If a law says something about noun A, noun B, noun C,  a person will often specifically say "Caused noun B" rather than use a corresponding verb.  Hence you'll  see sentences such as "the defendant caused grievous bodily harm to the victim", not "the defendant grievously harmed the victim's body"; you'll see the form "the defendant committed a hit and run" rather than "the defendant hit and ran"; more often "was driving while intoxicated" instead of "drove while intoxicated".

This helps them communicate because they understand that the intention is to be using the words in the exact sense of the statute, decision, etc.